# How do I get a list of files that have been `required` in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, metaprogramming

This is purely an experiment, but I'm wondering if it's possible to get a list of the `require`'d gems at runtime via some kind of metaprogramming. For example, say I have:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'nokogiri'

# don't know what to do here
```

How can I print out the following at runtime?

```
this app needs rubygems, sinatra, nokogiri
```

Comment: If $LOADED_FEATURES didn't exist, you could monkeypatch require to do what you wanted.

Comment: This question has neat answers using `Gem`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747990/is-there-any-way-to-tell-which-gems-and-plugins-are-loaded-at-runtime-for-a-rail

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can't do this exactly, because requiring one file may require others, and Ruby can't tell the difference between the file that *you* required and the file that someone else required.

You can check out `$LOADED_FEATURES` for a list of every single thing that's been required. But you should use [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) if you want to specify dependencies explicitly.

Here's a thoroughly imperfect way to guess at the gem names and enumerate everything:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > $LOADED_FEATURES.
   select { |feature| feature.include? 'gems' }.
   map { |feature| File.dirname(feature) }.
   map { |feature| feature.split('/').last }.
   uniq.sort
 => ["1.9.1", "action_dispatch", "action_pack", "action_view", "actions", "active_model", "active_record", "active_support", "addressable", "agent", "array", "aws", "builder", "bundler", "cache_stores", "cancan", "cdn", "class", "client", "common", "compute", "connection", "control", "controllers", "core", "core_ext", "core_extensions", "css", "data_mapper", "decorators", "dependencies", "dependency_detection", "deprecation", "devise", "digest", "dns", "encodings", "encryptor", "engine", "errors", "excon", "ext", "failure", "faraday", "fields", "fog", "formatador", "geographer", "haml", "hash", "helpers", "heroku_san", "hmac", "hooks", "hoptoad_notifier", "html", "http", "i18n", "idna", "importers", "inflector", "initializers", "instrumentation", "integrations", "interpolate", "interval_skip_list", "jquery-rails", "json", "kaminari", "kernel", "lib", "mail", "metric_parser", "mime", "mixins", "model_adapters", "models", "module", "mongo_mapper", "mongoid", "multibyte", "new_relic", "node", "nokogiri", "numeric", "oauth", "object", "omniauth", "orm_adapter", "package", "parser", "parsers", "plugin", "pp", "providers", "queued", "rack", "rails", "railtie", "redis", "request", "request_proxy", "resp    ruby-1.9.2-p180 :008 >onse", "resque", "retriever_methods", "routing", "ruby_extensions", "ruby_flipper", "rubygems", "runtime", "samplers", "sass", "sax", "script", "scss", "selector", "sequel", "ses", "shell", "signature", "simple_geo", "state_machine", "stats_engine", "storage", "strategies", "string", "tar_reader", "template", "terremark", "thor", "tokens", "tree", "treetop", "twitter", "us", "util", "vendor", "version_specific", "visitors", "warden", "xml", "xml_mini", "xpath", "xslt"]
```

Comment: `$"` is alias for `$LOADED_FEATURES`

Answer (score 27):

Here's a way to get all the calls to require.  Create this file: show_requires.rb

```
alias :orig_require :require
def require s
  print "Requires #{s}\n" if orig_require(s)
end
```

Then start your app with

> ruby -r show_requires.rb myapp.rb

This produces something like:

```
C:\code\test>ruby -r show_requires.rb test.rb
Requires stringio
Requires yaml/error
Requires syck
Requires yaml/ypath
Requires yaml/basenode
Requires yaml/syck
Requires yaml/tag
Requires yaml/stream
Requires yaml/constants
Requires date/format
Requires date
Requires yaml/rubytypes
Requires yaml/types
Requires yaml
Requires etc
Requires dl
Requires rbreadline
Requires readline
```

If you want only the top-level requires, add a global to track the nesting level:

```
$_rq_lvl = 0
alias :orig_require :require
def require s
  $_rq_lvl+=1
  print "Requires #{s}\n" if orig_require(s) and $_rq_lvl == 1
  $_rq_lvl -=1
end
```

Then you get:

```
C:\code\test>ruby -r require_test.rb test.rb
Requires yaml
Requires readline
```

Comment: Thanks for this post. This got me closer to what I was looking for than the accepted answer. However I only got the results I needed by monkey patching this into Kernel

Comment: It fails with some `/lib/bundler.rb:85:in ui': uninitialized constant #<Class:Bundler>::UI (NameError)`, probably because bundler uses `autoload`.

Answer (score 2):

Just a slight touch to add to the previous -- consider that in order to precisely replace the behaviour of #require then you must also return a boolean value, so this is a more faithful override:

```
module Kernel
  alias :orig_require :require
  def require(name)
    print "Requiring #{name}"
    is_okay = orig_require(name)
    puts " - #{is_okay ? 'Yup!' : 'Nope :('}"
    is_okay
  end
end
```

Interestingly with some testing I was doing -- tracking down a chain of stuff blowing up when requiring a module -- then this became necessary!