# No require 'date' statement on my ruby file but I can call DateTime.now

Tags: ruby, rubygems, docker-container

I am trying to understand how importing files in ruby works. But I almost spent a whole day
figuring out why I can call `DateTime.now` in my class where I didn't `require 'date`, these are all running on docker container instance where I get ruby 3.0.3
What got me stuck is when I tried to make a new ruby file on a new docker container instance ruby 3.0.3. And try calling `DateTime.now` it doesn't work.

I tried looking for require statement that has the word date in it in the project where I can call `DateTime.now` but no luck finding.

gem file of the project where I can call DateTime without require statement

```
gem 'aws-sdk-s3', '~> 1.93'
gem 'mime-types'
gem 'optparse', '~> 0.1.0'

group :development do
  gem 'rubocop', '~> 1.12'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec', '~> 3.10'
  gem 'rubocop-rspec', '~> 2.2'
  gem 'webmock', '~> 3.12'
end
```

gem file of the new project where I couldn't call DateTime without require statement

```
gem 'mime-types'
gem 'optparse', '~> 0.1.0'
gem 'gqli'

group :development do
  gem 'rubocop', '~> 1.12'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec', '~> 3.10'
  gem 'rubocop-rspec', '~> 2.2'
  gem 'webmock', '~> 3.12'
  gem 'test-unit', '~> 3.0'
end
```

the only difference is the aws and gqli in both project but I tried having both of them have the same gem file it still doesn't work.

Comment: I tried to reproduce here from a single ruby file with your first Gemfile, and if I simple perform a `DateTime.now` it raises the error commented by you. In the aws gem we can [clearly see that it includes the gem date](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/a82c8981c95a8296ffb6269c3c06a4f551d87f7d/gems/aws-sdk-core/lib/aws-sdk-core/param_converter.rb#L4), which explains why `DateTime` works along with `aws-sdk-s3 gem`.

Comment: You may find the selected answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190015/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-files-that-have-been-required-in-ruby) helpful for questions such as yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you [`require`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-require) the [`aws-sdk-s3` library](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/version-3/gems/aws-sdk-s3/lib/aws-sdk-s3.rb), which is part of the  [`aws-sdk-s3` Gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/aws-sdk-s3), the library, in turn, [`require`s the `aws-sdk-core` library](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/version-3/gems/aws-sdk-s3/lib/aws-sdk-s3.rb#L13):

> ```ruby
> # frozen_string_literal: true
>
> # WARNING ABOUT GENERATED CODE
> #
> # This file is generated. See the contributing guide for more information:
> # https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/version-3/CONTRIBUTING.md
> #
> # WARNING ABOUT GENERATED CODE
>
>
> require 'aws-sdk-kms'
> require 'aws-sigv4'
> require 'aws-sdk-core'
> #↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
> ```

The [`aws-sdk-core` library](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/version-3/gems/aws-sdk-core/lib/aws-sdk-core.rb), which is part of the [`aws-sdk-core` Gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/aws-sdk-core), in turn, loads the [`param_converter` library](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/version-3/gems/aws-sdk-core/lib/aws-sdk-core/param_converter.rb) using [`Kernel#require_relative`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-require_relative), as you can [see here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/version-3/gems/aws-sdk-core/lib/aws-sdk-core.rb#L40):

> ```ruby
> # client modules
>
> require_relative 'aws-sdk-core/client_stubs'
> require_relative 'aws-sdk-core/async_client_stubs'
> require_relative 'aws-sdk-core/eager_loader'
> require_relative 'aws-sdk-core/errors'
> require_relative 'aws-sdk-core/pageable_response'
> require_relative 'aws-sdk-core/pager'
> require_relative 'aws-sdk-core/param_converter'
> #↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
> ```

The `param_converter` library then, in turn, [loads the `date` library](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/version-3/gems/aws-sdk-core/lib/aws-sdk-core/param_converter.rb#L4):

> ```ruby
> # frozen_string_literal: true
>
> require 'stringio'
> require 'date'
> #↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
> ```

The `aws-sdk-core` Gem [does not depend on the `date` Gem](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/version-3/gems/aws-sdk-core/aws-sdk-core.gemspec#L15-L18):

```ruby
> spec.add_dependency('jmespath', '~> 1', '>= 1.6.1') # necessary for secure jmespath JSON parsing
> spec.add_dependency('aws-partitions', '~> 1', '>= 1.651.0') # necessary for new endpoint resolution
> spec.add_dependency('aws-sigv4', '~> 1.5') # necessary for making Aws::STS, SSO, SSOOIDC API calls
> spec.add_dependency('aws-eventstream', '~> 1', '>= 1.0.2') # necessary for binary eventstream
```

But you don't have to depend on the [`date` Gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/date) in order to use the [`date` library](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/exts/date/table_of_contents.html), because the `date` Gem is a [*default Gem*](https://stdgems.org/date/), which means it is part of Ruby's standard library, gets maintained by the Ruby developers, doesn't need to be installed, doesn't need to be listed as a Gem dependency, and doesn't need to be activated.

So, that's why you don't have to `require` the `date` library yourself: because you `require` a library, which in turn `require`s another library, which in turn `require_relative`s another library, which in turn `require`s the `date` library.

But the more interesting question is, *should* you `require` the `date` library? And the answer is, *Yes*, you should. Relying on a `require` chain like this is extremely brittle: what if some library somewhere in the middle down this chain decides to change its internal structure and, e.g. validate dates using a different library or implement date validation themselves? Then your code breaks for no apparent reason.

The rule that I generally follow is that *every script must stand on its own*, i.e. every script must `require` all of its dependencies.

Now, in larger applications, this might get annoying, and might even lead to high startup latencies. A good example would be framework or a DSL, where it is simply *expected* that the framework or the DSL provides a set of libraries for you that are already pre-loaded. Imagine, you had to `require` every `active_support` library, `active_model` library, `active_relation` library, etc. you are using in a Ruby on Rails application. That would be stupid: if you write a Ruby on Rails model, you *know* that `active_model` is loaded, you don't need to load it again.

So, a slightly relaxed rule is: *every script that is intended to be `require`d or executed by a client must stand on its own*. Scripts that are internal to the application may rely on internal knowledge about which libraries are already `required`.