# How can I see what gems are currently in the ruby environment?

Tags: ruby, jruby

My goal is, after running a script that may have some requires in it (or before), to see all of the gems that are loaded into my current environment.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Gem.loaded_specs.keys
```

(found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747990/is-there-any-way-to-tell-which-gems-and-plugins-are-loaded-at-runtime-for-a-rail))